# android -> XMPP / MSSQL -> .NET

Tags: android, .net, sql-server, xmpp

I am planing to make solution, which is able to send commands from mobile device to .NET app.
Example: I run android app. In the app I push "Start Winamp on PC" button. Then Winamp on PC starts playing immediately. 
Components I am planing to use:

1. Android app (to send command to web service)
2. .NET web service (it receives command from android, checks with MS-SQL database if this command is NOT disabled. If not disabled, it immediately sends the command to XMPP).
3. XMPP server catches the command and sends to .NET application (on PC) immediately. Then .NET app executes command (for example runs Winamp or any other action).

Is this good mechanism? Will it work?
Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, this approach will work.  Try using [XEP-0050](http://xmpp.org/extensions/xep-0050.html) as your protocol:

```
<iq type='set' to='responder@domain' id='exec1'>
  <command xmlns='http://jabber.org/protocol/commands'
           node='start-winamp'
           action='execute'/>
</iq>
```